# How to see boilerplate code for top-level statements in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm going through [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-console?view=vs-2022) C# intro tutorial by MS, and in the section "Fix the "format" error" I'm supposed to delete code in the namespace, but I'm not seeing that namespace since I'm in the "top-level statements" mode. How do I reveal the boilerplate code that is underneath?

Comment: If you don't have `namespace Calculator{}` then type it. If you have `namespace Calculator;` and nothing else, that's equivalent.

Comment: When you start a new project, you can opt out of top-level statements. This may give a more matching initial state

Answer (score 1):

As described by [Top-level statements - programs without Main methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements):

> Starting in C# 9, you don't have to explicitly include a Main method in a console application project. Instead, you can use the top-level statements feature to minimize the code you have to write. In this case, the compiler generates a class and Main method entry point for the application.
>
> Here's a Program.cs file that is a complete C# program in C# 10:
>
> ```c#
> Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
> ```
>
> Top-level statements let you write simple programs for small utilities such as Azure Functions and GitHub Actions. They also make it simpler for new C# programmers to get started learning and writing code.

This means that the Top-Level statements is a feature of a comiler, not of the editor. The Main method and the class (things you call "boilerplate") are not present in the source code - they are generated by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above answer is its Compiler feature.

> The compiler generates a method to serve as the program entry point
> for a project with top-level statements. The name of this method isn't
> actually Main, it's an implementation detail that your code can't
> reference directly. The signature of the method depends on whether the
> top-level statements contain the await keyword or the return
> statement.

The following table shows what the method signature would look like, using the method name Main in the table for convenience.

[image]

**Reference**:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements#implicit-entry-point-method

Answer (score 0):

Whoever updated the tutorial to .NET 6 with top-level statements ([see the commit](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/commit/5be16ce89f60e5e6e079887058bbf30e294e99f4#diff-0d677f10a68f5f8ff427e7c0d6a95f048f277849841ae430bb7f363d0f2ab8bb)) forgot to update the part in question. To see the full previous version of the code you can switch tutorial to VS 2019 version either by using dropdown at the top of table of contents:

[image]

Or just by following this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-console?view=vs-2019).

The previous version also should work, you should be able to replace the contents of your `Program.cs` file with code from this [section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-console?view=vs-2019#add-code-to-create-a-calculator) and proceed with tutorial from here.